# Append array items to itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have:

html:

```
<div>
  <a class="1"></a>
  <a class="2"></a>
  <a class="3"></a>
  <a class="4"></a>
</div>
```

js:

```
item = $('div a');
```

Which gives me an array of the 'a' elements. I want to add these elements again to the same array, so I tried:

```
item.push(item);
```

but what I ended up with is:

```
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[[a],[a],[a],[a]]
```

instead of

```
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
```

What can I do to achieve this result?

Comment: Not sure what your asking?

Comment: At first place - it's not an array, but a jquery object

Comment: You want to do what now? It's not an array, it's an array-like object, and it can't contain the same element multiple times.

Comment: what you are trying achieve...

Comment: jQuery uses `$.unique` behind the scene, so you can't do that. You should `.get()` the array and then push the duplicates.

Comment: @BlackSheep - Then the question becomes, why would you ever need an array with the same element multiple times ?

Comment: While answers have shown that it is possible to do this, you will probably run into problems later on. What exactly are you trying to achieve by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try this:

*edit*: Forgot to add a **[working fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/KbdKx/)**

```
item = $('div a');
$.merge(item,item);
```

Comment: Yep . . . that's the one.  I'm still curious as to what the point would be though.   LOL

Comment: @adeneo, thanks i've updated my answer with a fiddle.

Comment: It's interesting that in documentation they don't state it should work with jquery objects

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all. I thought jQuery deduplicates the element set.

Comment: @Felix Kling: it doesn't have chance when this function is used. It modifies the collection from outside and doesn't notify it https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L365

Comment: @Felix Kling: probably that's why in the documentation it's not mentioned as a use case :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to create an array with those elements, you could try this:

```
item = item.toArray();
item = item.concat(item);
```

Or this, which will work for arrays *or* jQuery objects:

```
item.push.apply(item, item);
```

Comment: `Object [object Object] has no method 'concat'`

Comment: How about you try it first, there is no jQuery concat method

Comment: @Matt The reason you are ending up with the first result is because you are adding [a, a, a] as an element...not as a set of individual variables. Concat will put those items together.

Comment: @zerkms / adeneo Oops, Corrected.

Comment: Concat is a base javascript function, it's not jQuery... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Comment: Btw, jquery's push is marked as "for internal usage only" https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L114

Comment: How about `Array.prototype.push.apply(item, item)`? :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @Tibos: it's not an array, not sure if the implementation/a standard guarantees to work with `item` passed as a first argument

Comment: Nice. i didn't know about the `$.fn.toArray` method.

Comment: @zerkms It seems to work (at least in Chrome), and it even remains a jQuery object. But I agree it's kind of strange.

Comment: @zermkms Array methods work on array-like objects. Push for example does something similar to `arr[arr.length]=x; arr.length++;`.

Comment: @Tibos: I'm not that confident in the ECMAScript standard to know that. If you say so - ok :-)

Comment: @Tibos - array methods do work with array-like objects, such as nodeLists. I don't know if jQuery objects are exactly the same as the native array-like objects in composition, but generally array methods does not work on jQuery objects, and passing `item` as the scope to `apply` and then passing `item` again as the value, seems a little hinky to me, even if it works ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go one by one

```
var itemsA = $('div a');

for(var i = 0; i<itemsA.length; i++){
 items.push(itemsA[i]);
}
```

What you were doing was pushing ALL the elements that  $('div a') returned into one single position of items.

Comment: Note however if you do anything with this jquery object that causes a new jquery object to be created, the duplicates will be removed from the object.